# Force Spotlight to index a normally un-indexed folder

Tags: terminal, finder, spotlight

Spotlight only indexes a limited number of folders and doesn't index all of the files on your system. This makes sense and for the average user this usually isn't a problem. However, I recently discovered an annoying side-effect: Image files in a a non-indexed folder **do not** show their image dimensions in the Finder!

[image]
*Screenshot shows that a image which was non-indexed does not have any dimensions.*

Is there any way of telling Spotlight to *include* a normally un-indexed folder in it's index to ensure that the dimensions are shown in the Finder?

Comment: I wanted to recommend `mdimport` but while this is successfull in adding new files/directories it doesn't seem to update the dimensions. Grrr.

Comment: Here’s a [neat trick to index folders that are excluded by rule](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/406849/5472) of the name of the path...

Answer (score 1):

Well, in order to answer the implicit question stated in your headline: You can force Spotlight to index unindexed folders by creating a link to them in an indexed folder. Say you want to index something under ~/Library/, you'll be able to do that by creating a link under your home directory.

Unfortunately, I can't answer your question proper: While this makes Spotlight comments etc. accessible, it still does not cause image dimensions to appear in Finder. But perhaps this is a starting point.