# Force Spotlight to index a hidden directory

Tags: finder, spotlight, big-sur

Microsoft `pwsh` stores its artifacts (scripts and modules) in the `~/.local/share/powershell`.

I've noticed that Spotlight doesn't index the content of this folder.

Is there a way to get Spotlight to index selected, hidden directories?

** edit **

I have a symlink on my desktop to the `powershell` directory:

```
$ ls  -al ~/Desktop

...
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff      36 Sep 24 08:52 powershell -> /Users/me/.local/share/powershell
```

This does not appear to have any effect on the indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotlight doesn't index dot files or folders. A workaround is to rename the folder and then symlink it back to its original name:

```
mv ~/.local/share/powershell ~/powershell && ln -s ~/powershell ~/.local/share/powershell
```

Make sure the destination of the move doesn't already exist.